# python import pandas- import is OK, but module not available in function

Tags: python, pandas, import, pycharm

I have a strange problem with importing pandas.

Here my import:

```
import pandas as pd
# ... more imports here
```

The import works fine.

Then I have a function main:

```
def main ():

   # here pd is not available during execution
   # for example
   print (pd)
```

The expected output should be something like:

`<module 'pandas from/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py'>`

But I get an
`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pd' referenced before assignment`

And now it is getting really, really strange:

If I run the programm in IDE (PyCharm 2022.3.1) and set a breakpoint at the print statement I can see that pd is defined at this point

I can also fire a 'print (pd)' statement in the *PyCharm console* and it works. But in the programm code it is still not working.

Just to make it double clear: I test for existence of `pd` exactly one line before it is referenced in the regular program

It is also not working if I run it from shell with python . So it seems not to be an issue from PyCharm.

I use Python 3.10. and pandas 1.5.0 on MacOS Ventura.

Comment: Are you making a variable named as `pd` inside main?

Comment: no, there is no assignment for pd

Comment: One more detaill I observed:
When I run the code not in main() function, instead with the `if __name__ == "__main__":` statement it works fine - I have on idea where this might coming from.

Comment: I can't post a answer right now, but you can add `global pd` statement inside your main function to resolve this issue

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Comment: @AdityaSoni why would you use `global` for an import?

Comment: Unfortunately it is a little big with 1000 locs - I know I should not do it ... 

Here are the other imports - maybe that helps:

```
import sys

import os
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

Comment: @Guy I wouldn't use a global for an import, but I think this is caused due to renaming the module to pd, try using pandas only, it should work.

Comment: @AdityaSoni there is nothing wrong in this way of importing `pandas` (or any other library). Even in the docs `pandas` is imported like this.

Comment: @Guy This may be an bug in `python3.10`, because I never encountered this type of problem?

Comment: I just tried what @AdityaSoni mentioned, not to rename the import and it works !

Comment: python3.8 here. Got your code working without any problems... Perhaps you are having an environment path problem (meaning, your IDE points to the correct environment where pandas is installed, but for some reason your RunTime Env. is pointing to a different path where pandas is _not_ installed)?

Answer (score -2):

Not renaming pandas to pd solved the problem.

Just using `import pandas` NOT `import pandas as pd` solved the problem.

Seems specific to pandas and the mentioned versions.

This issue is not related with PyCharm.

Using a `global pd` statement may also work, but I did not try.

Comment: This is very unlikely, Pycharm sometimes goes a little crazy, invalidating cache and restart (from the File tab) would probably solve the issue.

Comment: Would you like to accept my answer, if I post?

Comment: Please avoid posting comments into answers